# Devise edit on custom view without current_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to put profile edit capabilities on to a custom '/info' page without needing current_password. It only works when you enter your current_password. Without the current password no error happens but it redirects to the unsuccessful update path specified in the controller.

I have a registrations_controller that overrides the devise one:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def info
    @user = current_user
    if @user 
        render :info
    else
        render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
     end 
end

def update
@user = User.find(current_user.id)

successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
  @user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update))

else

  params[:user].delete(:current_password)
  @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update))

end

if successfully_updated
  set_flash_message :notice, :updated

  sign_in @user, :bypass => true
  redirect_to user_path(current_user)
 else
  redirect_to user_path(current_user)
 end
end

def needs_password?(user, params)
 user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
  params[:user][:password].present?
end


protected

def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
 '/info'
end

def needs_password?(user, params)
  user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
    params[:user][:password].present?
 end  
end
```

application_controller:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :image) }
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation, :image) }
end
```

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
devise_scope :user do
get "/info" => "registrations#info"
end
```

info.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put}) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<%= f.input :image %>
<%= f.submit "Update", class: "button5"%>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want it to require the password, you could either get rid of the `if needs_password? / else` code and just use `update_without_password` all the time -- or you could define `needs_password?` to always return false.

Note: your `needs_password?` method is defined twice in your sample code.

Comment: Very simple fix. Thanks so much.